# vscode remote container extension launching got stuck at "installing extensions"

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I am using this remote container extension for launching a container, sometime it will stuck at "installing extensions".
It will stuck at this state as follow for a long time and no response.

[image: screen shot]

Sometime it works fine and fast, sometime does not.
I have commented all the extensions in devcontainer.json file but it still happens sometime.
I dont know whether it a network issue or something else. And I want to know how can I make it stable?
Thanks!

This is my devcontainer.json.

```
{
"name": "gazebo_ros_docker",
"dockerFile": "Dockerfile",
"extensions": [
    // "ms-iot.vscode-ros",
    // "ms-vscode.cpptools",
    // "mhutchie.git-graph"
],
"runArgs": [
    "-it",
    "--rm",
    "--privileged",
    "-e ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost",
    "-e ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311",
    "--name=ros_container",
    ],
"settings": {
    "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash"
},
// "postCreateCommand": "bash /catkin_ws/src/panda_simulation/scripts/docker-setup.sh",
"workspaceMount": "source=${localWorkspaceFolder},target=/catkin_ws,type=bind",
// "workspaceMount": "source=${localWorkspaceFolder},target=/catkin_ws,type=bind,consistency=delegated",
"workspaceFolder": "/catkin_ws",
"mounts": [
    "source=/tmp/.X11-unix,target=/tmp/.X11-unix,type=bind",
],
"containerEnv": {
    "DISPLAY": "${localEnv:DISPLAY}",
},
"containerUser": "docker_ros"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not find the best way to solve this problem. But I export the images of the vscode-processed container and launch it. It is working well now.